# ShowMessage() behavoir in FireMonkey on iOS

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I have a simple FMX multi-device C++ app.  The app has 1 Form and nothing else.  In the Form's `OnShow` event, I initiate a function I named `StartupCode()`.  All of the code is shown below.

When I run the app on **Windows**, I get expected behavior - the 3 messages pop up in the correct order with the correct timing (e.g. each `Sleep()` only starts after the previous dialog box has been acknowledged by clicking OK).

When I run the app on **iOS** or **Android**, I get the last message popup first ("Slept 2 sec") but only after the entire time has elapsed (12.25 seconds).  Then immediately after acknowledging by clicking OK, I get the "Slept 10 sec" message, and likewise after that I get the "Slept quarter sec" message.

```
#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>

void StartupCode()
{
    Sleep(250);
    ShowMessage("Slept quarter sec");
    Sleep(10000); 
    ShowMessage("Slept 10 sec");
    Sleep(2000); 
    ShowMessage("Slept 2 sec");
}

void __fastcall TForm1::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
{
    #if defined(_PLAT_IOS) || defined(_PLAT_ANDROID)
      TThread::ForceQueue(nullptr, [this](){StartupCode();});
    #endif

    #if defined(_PLAT_MSWINDOWS)
      StartupCode();
    #endif
}
```

I'm green and just trying to learn a bit.  I was testing to see if a thread would get into trouble with Apple's app start watchdog timers when I ran into this weird behavior.

Why does this behavior happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `ShowMessage()` simply behaves differently on mobile platforms in 10.2 Tokyo than what you are expecting.

Per the [10.2 Tokyo documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Dialogs.ShowMessage):

> **ShowMessage Behaves Differently On Different Platforms**
>
> On desktop platforms, `ShowMessage` behaves synchronously. The call finishes only when the user closes the dialog box.
>
> **On mobile platforms `ShowMessage` behaves asynchronously. The call finishes instantaneously, it does not wait for the user to close the dialog box**.
>
> If you want to force a specific behavior across different platforms, use [`IFMXDialogServiceAsync.ShowMessageAsync`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Platform.IFMXDialogServiceAsync.ShowMessageAsync) or [`IFMXDialogServiceSync.ShowMessageSync`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Platform.IFMXDialogServiceSync.ShowMessageSync) from the [`FMX.Platform`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Platform) unit.

Per the [10.0 Seattle documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.Dialogs.ShowMessage):

> **On mobile platforms, calls to `ShowMessage` are not blocking. This means that any code that you place after a call to `ShowMessage` is executed before the dialog box closes**. If you need to execute code after your dialog box closes, use [`MessageDlg`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.Dialogs.MessageDlg) instead of `ShowMessage`.

So, what is happening in your case is that your calls to `ShowMessage()` are returning back to `StartupCode()` immediately, queuing up the dialogs in the background.  Then all of the calls to `Sleep()` are processed, and then execution returns back to the main UI loop, which then displays all 3 dialogs at the same time, one on top of the other, with the first one on the bottom and the last one on the top.  That is why you see them appear in reverse order.

---

Note: Android does not support modal/synchronous dialogs! And as such, `IFMXDialogServiceSync.ShowMessageSync()` is not implemented on Android, only `IFMXDialogServiceAsync.ShowMessageAsync()` is implemented.

Prior to 10.1 Berlin, `ShowMessage()` internally called the **synchronous** version of  [`IFMXDialogService.MessageDialog()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.IFMXDialogService.MessageDialog) (contrary to what the Seattle documentation above says), which worked on iOS but raised an `ENotImplemented` exception on Android.

### `ShowMessage()` (and `MessageDlg()`) was [deprecated in 10.1 Berlin](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/What_Was_New_in_Berlin#Simplified_Dialog_API).

I don't have 10.1 Berlin or 10.2 Tokyo installed to check what `ShowMessage()` does internally on those systems, but it sounds like it was updated to use `IFMXDialogServiceAsync.ShowMessageAsync()` on both iOS and Android, if you are not getting an `ENotImplemented` exception on Android.

---

Note: the behavior you are seeing has NOTHING to do with `TThread::ForceQueue()` (which is [broken on Android in 10.2 Tokyo](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-17841), BTW).  Also, `TThread::ForceQueue()` does not start a new thread, like you claimed.

Comment: Remy - thank you very much.  You are literally the master.  I'd have given up before I got started good with this IDE if not for your patient help.  So TThread doesn't start a new thread.  It looks like an earlier post on another topic you explain that TThread::ForceQueue is used to delay the assignment until after the FormShow() exits.  Is that what is happening here,  StartupCode() doesn't kick off until FormShow exits?

Comment: "*So TThread doesn't start a new thread*" - that is not what I said.  I said that `TThread::ForceQueue()` specifically doesn't start a new worker thread. Obviously, `TThread` itself does (that is its primary purpose). But yes, `ForceQueue()` is being used to delay `StartupCode()` from running until after `FormShow()` exits. `ForceQueue()` doesn't need to start a new worker thread to perform that delay when called in the main UI thread (unlike [`TThread::Queue()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Queue), which delays only when called by a worker thread).